# How to downgrage Python version from 3.9.12 to Python < 3.9 only for project in virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have Python 3.9.12 installed. However I want Python version lower than 3.9 to be running inside a venv (and keep Python 3.9 for other projects). How can I do this? I am using VS code and Terminal there.

I have run `source ./venv/bin/activate`

Comment: please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

Comment: @Scb thanks for the answer, after checking this reference 'Please note that venv does not permit creating virtual environments with other versions of Python.' for python3. Do I need to completely uninstall Python and install with a new version?

Comment: No, you need to install a new version. No need to uninstall the old one.

Comment: According to the comments it was still possible, I haven't tested it and I use [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) instead which should work just fine